# IF Statement does not work well inside for loop

Tags: java

In below code, I want to let user to enter one of available student IDs on search box, then if student ID is valid a simple message box will appear with available student ID.

**Situation 1:** When I enter 212 in search box it works well.

**Situation 2:** When I enter 215 or 219 or 214 (NOT 212), it jumps to NOT FOUND message box and after two more tries I get a message box with found student ID.

**Question** Why I don't get found message box if I enter 215 or 219 or 214 for first time but it works well when I enter 212? What is wrong in this for loop or IF Statement? Why when I enter 215, it ignores first and second times then it shows found message box?

```
import javax.swing.*;
static int[] studentID = {212,214,215,219};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    search();

    System.exit(0);

}

public static void search(){
    for(int i = 0;i < studentID.length;i++){
        search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a student ID");
        if(studentID[i] == Integer.parseInt(search)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, studentID[i]);
            break;
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"NOT FOUND!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should keep a flag in your loop. Only after the last iteration should you check whether or not the element was found.

Comment: You probably don't even need a loop. Just get the input and use `java.util.Arrays.binarySearch()` to check if it matches any value in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop should be after the input is read, and the "NOT FOUND" message should be after the loop:

```
public static void search(){
    search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a student ID");
    for(int i = 0;i < studentID.length;i++){
        if(studentID[i] == Integer.parseInt(search)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, studentID[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
    OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"NOT FOUND!!!");
}
```

If you want to perform multiple searches, you should call the `search()` method multiple times.

Comment: Yeah this answer is solution. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Stackoverflow1 {
    static int[] studentID = {212,214,215,219};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        search();

        System.exit(0);

    }

    public static void search(){
        String enter_a_student_id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a student ID");

        for(int i = 0;i < studentID.length;i++){
            if(studentID[i] == Integer.parseInt(enter_a_student_id)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, studentID[i]);
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"NOT FOUND!!!");



    }
}
```